# Improvement With Xpath Search?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I am a student learning selenium and trying to set a checkbox(by placing a tick) that resides on the same row as a target document.  Here is how the row looks:

```
            <span><input>Checkbox</input></span> - <span>_lblDocumentCategoryDescription</span> - <span>_lblDocumentdescription</span>
```

Each row consists of a checkbox for that row, a category and a description.  I am provided the description and need to set the corresponding checkbox at the beginning of the row.

Although I have a solution that works I am looking for a better method as my method is very slow and I can call it multiple times, compounding the slowness.  The page in question has 315 fixed different documents that might possibly be added (to a merge and print feature). I usually add at least 3 rows so need to run the search

I am currently using xpath to search since my knowledge of CSS is limited and it seems like traversing up the DOM (no :parent?) is not easy unless using some javascript, which I am trying to avoid.  I have read that executing JS doesn't emulate the user correctly so I guess xpath is the solution?

As I know there must be a quicker/better/more efficient solution I am hoping others might have found better?

Here is what I am currently using:

Method Call
                CPTools,setStupidCheckbox("Sublease Addendum", true);

Method:

```
            public CPTools setStupidCheckbox(String documentToPrint, Boolean onIfTrue) {
                    this.log.trace("Starting: setStupidCheckbox; parameter: documentToPrint " + documentToPrint);
                    String xpathForCheckboxes = "/ancestor::tr//input";
                    try {
                        String xpathForDocumentDescriptions = String.format("//span[contains(text(), '%s')]", documentToPrint);
                        tools.waitForElement(By.xpath(xpathForDocumentDescriptions), 2);
                        if (driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathForDocumentDescriptions)).isDisplayed()) {
                            driver.findElementByXPath(xpathForDocumentDescriptions + xpathForCheckboxes).click();
                        }
                    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException | ElementNotVisibleException e) {
                    }
                    this.log.trace("Ending: setStupidCheckbox");
                    return this;
                }
```

Here is the full xpath for a table row (the dynamic part of the id is the _ctl316):

```
            <tr class="DataGridCellData">
                <td class="DataGridCellDataCenterAligned">
                    <span class="DataLabel"><input id="ctl01_PageBody_grdDocument_ctl316_chkSelect" name="ctl01$PageBody$grdDocument$ctl316$chkSelect" onclick="javascript:uiHelper.GridCellCheck(this, 'chkAllSelect');" type="checkbox"></span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="ctl01_PageBody_grdDocument_ctl316_lblDocumentCategoryDescription">Approval Form</span>
                </td><td align="left">
                    <span id="ctl01_PageBody_grdDocument_ctl316_lblDocumentdescription">Sublease Addendum</span>
                </td><td align="center">
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Thanks in advance for any possible help.

Comment: which element you want to get  ?

Comment: How about "//input[contains(@onclick, 'chkAllSelect')]" ?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity in my question - I am trying to check the checkbox, but there are 315 of them - the only reference I know is the text that will be present in the document description span (Sublease Addendum).

Comment: @TarunLalwani - thanks for the comment - however that xpath will pick the very first  checkbox as all 315 have that same onclick.

Comment: Does the text `Approval Form` or `Sublease Addendum` related to the checkbox? Is that text different for your cell?

Comment: Are you using the term "check the checkbox" in the American sense of "place a tick in the checkbox" or in the British sense of "inspect the checkbox"?

Comment: @MichaelKay - Yes sorry , the American sense of "place a tick" is what I meant - I also used "trying to set a checkbox" in the original description buy I am tryingto "place a tick"

Comment: I would expect to see html of the whole thing related to One visual/logical row, so to make a sensible XPath.

Comment: @TarunLalwani - Sure makes sense.  I have posted a complete row in the code block in the original description

Comment: What is stopping you from locating elements by id? At the beginning of your test determine which dynamic id has been generated. Once you get this dynamic ID, build up the ID string within your solution and then pass this string to the findelement by id function. Could this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try below XPath if span text (Sublease Addendum) is unique:
//td[.= 'Sublease Addendum']

Comment: Thanks Kuldeep, I did try but this does not make the search any quicker than my method - I am not just looking for the string "Sublease Addendum" I am looking for a text that would be in that span - "Sublease Addendum is just one example I am using.  The xpath search through all 315 different items is slow and that is what I am looking for help with.  Thanks for trying though!